# ControlTemplate with a command binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF.I custom a tooglebutton in controltemplate and it has a command.I want to map the command click event to my custom control.

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                            <Grid Width="150" Height="100">
                                <Grid.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=PrimaryColor}"/>
                                </Grid.Background>
                                <TextBlock Text="+" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="64" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="LightGray"/>

                                <Grid Margin="0" Width="150" Height="100">
                                    <Grid.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.462063,0.00227975" EndPoint="0.462063,1.00111">
                                            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#66007099" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#4D0079AC" Offset="0.131072"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#350082C0" Offset="0.367442"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#030094E8" Offset="0.990952"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Grid.Background>
                                    <Grid.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="38" ShadowDepth="11.3386" Opacity="0.6" Color="#FF000000" Direction="270"/>
                                    </Grid.Effect>
                                </Grid>

                                </Grid>
                            </Viewbox>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Grid Margin="0">
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" Command="{x:Static my:ContainerButton.CloseCommand}" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ShowToolbar}" />
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

That is my xaml template,

```
    public class ContainerButton : ToggleButton{

    public ContainerButton() {
        closeCommand = new RoutedCommand("CloseCommand", typeof(ContainerButton));

        var binding = new CommandBinding() { Command = closeCommand };
        binding.Executed += OnCloseEvent;

        CommandBindings.Add(binding);
    }

    private void OnCloseEvent(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        Content = null;
        ShowToolbar = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CloseCommand", typeof(RoutedCommand), typeof(ContainerButton));

    private static RoutedCommand closeCommand;

    public static RoutedCommand CloseCommand {
        get {
            return closeCommand;
        }
    }}
```

And I used the control like

```
<local:ContainerButton x:Name="xToggle" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}"
                       PrimaryColor="Transparent" 
                       Margin="252,222,82,34" />
```

It works well when I build the project and run the application.I got an exception when I switch to xaml design view in visual studio 2010,
Visual studio throw an

> System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension.Member Exception.

I deleted `Command="{x:Static my:ContainerButton.CloseCommand}"` the custom control display fine in design mode. I do not know what 's wrong with it?

Comment: There might be a way to get this running, but you should know that the XAML designer (especially in VS 2010) is notoriously buggy. If it compiles and works when you run the application, your code is fine.

Comment: I got same  problem with my code in vs.net 2010、vs.net2012、vs.net2013 .Type “System.Windows.DependencyProperty” object can not convert to “System.String”.My code works fine except XAML designer throw the exception.

Comment: It seems to me this should be reproducible with a less-complicated code example. Did you really attempt to reduce your code to the bare minimum? As far as the specific problem, I haven't tried to reproduce this, but you might consider getting rid of the property; just use `public readonly static RoutedCommand CloseCommand = new RoutedCommand("CloseCommand", typeof(ContainerButton));` instead. Maybe the property access is confusing the designer (not that it should, but...)